# Adapting C# event containing ref parameter

Tags: c#, oop, events, adapter, abstraction

I'm in a situation where I have to use 3rd party library that contains a lot of events and is imho not very well written. It fires up events that I have to handle in my code, but I'm trying to abstract it away (to be able to unit test rest of my code dependent on that library) so I need an adapter. The problem is that some of the events are of delegate type that take `ref` parameters. Here's an example of how the 3rd party library looks like:

```
delegate void AdapteeEventHandler1(SpecificAdaptee sender, int a, int b);
delegate void AdapteeEventHandler2(SpecificAdaptee sender, ref int a); // problematic delegate

class SpecificAdaptee
{
    public event AdapteeEventHandler1 Event1;
    public event AdapteeEventHandler2 Event2; // problematic event

    /// <summary>Exercise Event1</summary>
    public void FireEvent1()
    {
        Event1?.Invoke(this, 1, 2);
    }
    /// <summary>Exercise Event2</summary>
    public void FireEvent2()
    {
        int a = 42;
        Event2?.Invoke(this, ref a);
    }
}
```

To show how I am abstracting regular event taking list of parameters, it contains `Event1` of type `AdapteeEventHandler1`. The problematic type is `AdapteeEventHandler2`, but let me show first how I am going about adapting the whole thing:

```
#region AdaptedEventArgs
class AdaptedEventArgs1 : EventArgs
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
}

class AdaptedEventArgs2 : EventArgs
{
    public int A { get; set; }
}
#endregion

/// <summary>These represent an abstraction layer between SpecificAdaptee and our own code</summary>
class Adaptor
{
    private readonly SpecificAdaptee _specificAdaptee;
    /// <summary>Maintains relationship between the event triggered by SpecificAdaptee and the adapted event.</summary>
    private readonly IAdaptedEventHandlerManager _adaptedEventHandlerManager;

    public Adaptor(SpecificAdaptee specificAdaptee, IAdaptedEventHandlerManager adaptedEventHandlerManager)
    {
        _specificAdaptee = specificAdaptee;
        _adaptedEventHandlerManager = adaptedEventHandlerManager;
    }

    #region Events
    /// <summary>Adapts SpecificAdaptee.Event1</summary>
    public event EventHandler<AdaptedEventArgs1> AdaptedEvent1
    {
        add
        {
            _specificAdaptee.Event1 += _adaptedEventHandlerManager.RegisterEventHandler<AdapteeEventHandler1>(value,
                (sender, a, b) => value.Invoke(this, new AdaptedEventArgs1 { A = a, B = b }));
        }
        remove
        {
            _specificAdaptee.Event1 -= _adaptedEventHandlerManager.UnregisterEventHandler<AdapteeEventHandler1>(value);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>Adapts SpecificAdaptee.Event2</summary>
    public event EventHandler<AdaptedEventArgs2> AdaptedEvent2
    {
        add
        {
            /* !!! ERROR HERE !!! */
            _specificAdaptee.Event2 += _adaptedEventHandlerManager.RegisterEventHandler<AdapteeEventHandler2>(value,
                (sender, a) => value.Invoke(this, new AdaptedEventArgs2 { A = a }));
        }
        remove
        {
            _specificAdaptee.Event2 -= _adaptedEventHandlerManager.UnregisterEventHandler<AdapteeEventHandler2>(value);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

So what is happening here is that when I register an event handler to `Adaptor.AdaptedEvent1` I am wrapping `EventHandler<AdaptedEventArgs1>` in `AdapteeEventHandler1` and register it to `SpecificAdaptee.Event1`, also converting the `AdaptedEventArgs1` to list of parameters required by `AdapteeEventHandler1`. This way user can register to events of `Adaptor` that will be fired when `SpecificAdaptee` fires its own events. Next I will post a program that exercises this but note that the problem is in `AdaptedEvent2`, where I would like to do things in an analogous manner, but I don't know how to deal with the `ref` parameter (there is a syntax error in `add` accessor of `AdaptedEvent2`.
Here is a console application exercising the project:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var specific = new SpecificAdaptee();
        var adapter = new Adaptor(specific, new AdaptedEventHandlerManager());

        adapter.AdaptedEvent1 += OnAdaptedEvent1;
        adapter.AdaptedEvent2 += OnAdaptedEvent2;

        specific.FireEvent1();
        specific.FireEvent2();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void OnAdaptedEvent1(object sender, AdaptedEventArgs1 args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(OnAdaptedEvent1)}({sender}, {args.A}, {args.B})");
    }

    private static void OnAdaptedEvent2(object sender, AdaptedEventArgs2 args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(OnAdaptedEvent2)}({sender}, {args.A})");
    }
}
```

So that's how it's supposed to work. I register to events of my `Adaptor` that I have in my code, and events get fired when the 3rd party library (`SpecificAdaptee`) fires its own events (here in this example, triggered by calling `specific.FireEvent1()` and 2).

For completeness, so you can try it yourself I include code for `AdaptedEventHandlerManager` that maps adapted event handlers to `SpecificAdaptee`'s handlers, so I can register and unregister multiple event handlers like I normally would do:

```
interface IAdaptedEventHandlerManager
{
    TSpecificEventHandler RegisterEventHandler<TSpecificEventHandler>(object adaptedEventHandler,
        TSpecificEventHandler specificEventHandler);

    TSpecificEventHandler UnregisterEventHandler<TSpecificEventHandler>(object adaptedEventHandler)
        where TSpecificEventHandler : class;
}

class AdaptedEventHandlerManager : IAdaptedEventHandlerManager
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Remembers relation between the specific handler and general handler. Important when unsubscribing from
    ///     events. Key is the general event handler we are registering to events of this class. Value are specific
    ///     event handlers.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly Dictionary<object, List<object>> _eventHandlers =
        new Dictionary<object, List<object>>();

    public TSpecificEventHandler RegisterEventHandler<TSpecificEventHandler>(object adaptedEventHandler,
        TSpecificEventHandler specificEventHandler)
    {
        List<object> eventHandlerList;
        if (!_eventHandlers.TryGetValue(adaptedEventHandler, out eventHandlerList))
        {
            eventHandlerList = new List<object> { specificEventHandler };
            _eventHandlers.Add(adaptedEventHandler, eventHandlerList);
        }
        else
        {
            eventHandlerList.Add(specificEventHandler);
        }
        return specificEventHandler;
    }

    public TSpecificEventHandler UnregisterEventHandler<TSpecificEventHandler>(object adaptedEventHandler)
        where TSpecificEventHandler : class
    {
        List<object> eventHandlerList;
        if (!_eventHandlers.TryGetValue(adaptedEventHandler, out eventHandlerList))
        {
            return null;
        }

        var eventHandler = eventHandlerList.FirstOrDefault();
        if (eventHandler != null)
        {
            eventHandlerList.Remove(eventHandler);
        }

        if (!eventHandlerList.Any())
        {
            _eventHandlers.Remove(adaptedEventHandler);
        }
        return eventHandler as TSpecificEventHandler;
    }
}
```

This basically remembers in a dictionary the adapted event handler, and the list of `SpecificAdaptee`'s handlers.

So my question: **is there a way to adapt events taking `ref` parameters without retracting to custom `delegate` type that takes a `ref` parameter**, so I can use standard `EventHandler<>` class with custom `EventArgs` descendant?

I realise it's quite a handful of code so please let me know if something is not clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: @mybirthname thanks for your comment. This is actually the shortest code I could produce that portrays both the desired behavior (AdaptedEvent1) and the problem (AdaptedEvent2) :(. I tried to emphasize the specific problem in the end of the post.

Comment: Are you simply using the value or do you need to manipulate `a`?

Comment: @toadflakz I am not yet completely familiar with how the 3rd party library operates, but as I stroll through the code I can see that essentially they use the `ref` params as `out`, so the intention is to set these values in the handler and "return" them to the caller. In other words I need to manipulate `a` (I think).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ref` parameter in the event is meant to set from the subscribers. Though it's a bad idea, the api which you're using works based on that.

You can take all the pain in the adapter class and make it work such that consumers are not polluted by the `ref` parameter. They can continue to use `EventArgs` style events.

```
public event EventHandler<AdaptedEventArgs2> AdaptedEvent2
{
    add
    {
        _specificAdaptee.Event2 += _adaptedEventHandlerManager.RegisterEventHandler<AdapteeEventHandler2>(value,
            (SpecificAdaptee sender, ref int a) =>
                {
                    var args = new AdaptedEventArgs2 { A = a };
                    value.Invoke(this, args);
                    a = args.A;
                });
    }
    remove
    {
        _specificAdaptee.Event2 -= _adaptedEventHandlerManager.UnregisterEventHandler<AdapteeEventHandler2>(value);
    }
}
```

After the event is executed, we set the value of `A` to the ref parameter `a`. This simulates the behavior of ref parameter and also abstracts it under the adapter class. If `A` is changed in the event handler, it will be reflected in the `SpecificAdaptee` class too.

To show how this works like a ref parameter:

```
class SpecificAdaptee
{
    ...
    public void FireEvent2()
    {
        int a = 42;
        if (Event2 != null)
            Event2(this, ref a);

        Console.WriteLine("A value after the event is {0}", a);
    }
}

private static void OnAdaptedEvent2(object sender, AdaptedEventArgs2 args)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(OnAdaptedEvent2)}({sender}, {args.A})");
    args.A = 15;
}
```

This prints:

```
A value after the event is 15
```

<sub>PS: For brevity I've added only the parts of your program which needs a change.</sub>

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you :)