# Dynamic event subscription with ref / out parameter

Tags: c#

I have been using an expression tree to create a delegate and subscribe to any event with an `Action<Object[]>`, where all the event parameters are converted to an array of objects.
This has been working fine until now, that I need to subscribe to an event with an out/ref parameter and I need to set the value of this parameter.

Is there a way to use something similar to the expression tree and subscribe to any event, but still be able to set/return values to the object that raised the event?

Expression tree to create a delegate:

```
public static Delegate CreateProxyWithDynamicParameters(this EventInfo EventInfo, Action<object[]> Action)
{
        var EventHandlerType = EventInfo.EventHandlerType;
        var InvokeMethodInfo = EventHandlerType.GetMethod("Invoke");

        var Parameters = InvokeMethodInfo.GetParameters().Select(Parameter => Expression.Parameter(Parameter.ParameterType, Parameter.Name)).ToArray();

        var ConvertedParameters = Parameters.Select(Parameter => Expression.Convert(Parameter, typeof(object))).Cast<Expression>().ToArray();

        var NewArrayInit = Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(object), ConvertedParameters);

        var Body = Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(Action), "Invoke", null, NewArrayInit);
        var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda(Body, Parameters);

        return Delegate.CreateDelegate(EventInfo.EventHandlerType, lambdaExpression.Compile(), InvokeMethodInfo.Name, ignoreCase: false);
}
```

Subscription with the delegate:

```
protected static void AddEvent<TMessage>(EventInfo eventInfo) where TMessage : EventArgs
{
        void EventAction(object[] e)
        {
            // Run some event code.
        }

        var @delegate = eventInfo.CreateProxyWithDynamicParameters(EventAction);
        DelegateDictionary[typeof(TMessage)] = @delegate;

        eventInfo.AddEventHandler(x.Target, @delegate);
}
```

Edit:

Here is a vanilla simple. Where I need to set the `HandlingCode` parameter.

```
InventorApplication.ApplicationEvents.OnSaveDocument += ApplicationEvents_OnSaveDocument;

private void ApplicationEvents_OnSaveDocument(_Document DocumentObject, EventTimingEnum BeforeOrAfter, NameValueMap Context, out HandlingCodeEnum HandlingCode)
{
    HandlingCode = HandlingCodeEnum.kEventHandled;
}
```

Comment: can you perhaps show the scenario if you were using vanilla simple event subscription in plain C#, so we can visualize the setup here? it isn't obvious to me where the `ref`/`out` is in the example above

Comment: Btw, in a somewhat similar question, there's an answer demonstrating how to wrap the `ref` parameter into `EventArgs`. I believe this can be done in Expression Trees. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40126943/adapting-c-sharp-event-containing-ref-parameter

Comment: @MarcGravell I added a normal operation sample.

Comment: Can you explain why "using an expression tree to create a delegate and subscribe to any event with an `Action<Object[]>`" is useful? What's the use case here?

Comment: @Enigmativity I'm was trying to abstract events from an API that I'm using so there will only be one point of contact and this approach helped with making a base class that can watch any event an notify other objects if an event was raised.

Comment: @Einir - So you're trying to create a bus for subscribing to events in a general purpose fashion?

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes, that was the idea.

Comment: @Einir - There are good libraries out there that do that already. Don't reinvent this wheel.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to struggle to do this with `Expression`, because `Expression` likes to be able to run things via reflection for fallback, and it can't handle refs via reflection. You *might* be able to do it via raw IL, but... that's getting messier and messier.

Frankly, this event API is making life hard for you. If you control that API, I *strongly* suggest using the more idiomatic `(object sender, SomeEventArgs args)` where `SomeEventArgs : EventArgs`. Your `SomeEventArgs` would then have *properties* for all the things you're trying to pass as parameters, and the interested code can just do:

```cs
args.HandlingCode = ...
```

to assign a value.

Comment: I have no control over the API and this is exactly what I was trying to do. Convert this event to a more standard event with an `EventArgs` class for parameters and trying to save me some code so I don't have to write a method for every event. But it looks like I will have to go with that approach, but that is ok, I was only curious is this can be done.